# Mapping beamer color (setbeamercolor) to definecolor

Tags: beamer, color

I use setbeamercolor and use parameter `white!90!green`. This is an example, `\setbeamercolor{block body example}{fg=black,bg=white!90!green}%`.

How can I map this color model to the LaTeX RGB color model?  I mean, when I have the color code `white!90!green`, how can I find the values A, B, C that matches the color in `\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{A, B, C}`?

Also, how do I interpret the `white!90!green`?

Comment: `white!90!green` means that the resulting colour is a mixture of 10% green and 90% white (see the documentation of the `xcolor` package for in-depth information). However I am not sure what you're actually asking in your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I map this color model to the LaTeX RGB color model?

With `\testcolor`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{240,120,0}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{testcolors}[rgb,RGB,cmyk,hsb,HTML]
\testcolor{white!90!green}
\testcolor{orange}
\testcolor{myorange}
\end{testcolors}
\end{document}
```

> Also, how do I interpret the white!90!green?

It should be evident in the rgb (lowercase) column, but is just that samcarter commented.