# What do you call, and how do you use, this "red!5!white" color syntax?

Tags: color, syntax

I've only ever seen this `red!5!white` sort of color notation with exclamation points and color names mixed with numbers in LaTeX. I want to learn how it works, but I don't know what it's called, so I don't know what term to search for. What is this?

Comment: It's the `xcolor` color-mixing syntax. Look for package xcolor documentation: https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor?lang=en

Comment: Use [\testcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411354/11604) if you want to know what is exactly this color in another notations as RGB.

Answer (score 2):

These are *standard color expressions* as [described by the `xcolor` package](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf#page=15). The short explanation of that syntax is that you're mixing those colors in proportion to those given numbers from left to right. An omitted color like in `red!75` is assumed to be white.

[image: screenshot of Figure 5 from the xcolor manual of some examples]