# xcolor specification

Tags: color

I want to define colours with `rgb` palette.  But I have found information like

```
Tiger Orange
Hex #F96815
RGB 249, 104, 21
CMYK 0, 58, 92, 2
```

When defining the colour, do the values have to be between `0.0` and `1.0`, or can one use the scheme for `Tiger Orange` above?

```
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1.0,0.0,0.0}
```

Comment: `RGB` instead of `rgb` for value between 0 and 255. And `HTML` for a CSS-style hexadecimal notation.

Comment: xcolor has a quite good documentation.

Comment: Does not look that `CMYK` can be whole values though.

Comment: No, `CMYK` does not exist. But typically, CMYK values are either going from 0 to 1 or from 0 to 100. So conversion is quite simple, since you just need to divide the above values by 100: `\definecolor{Tiger Orange}{cmyk}{0, .58, .92, .02}`.

Comment: [Test yourself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411354/11604)

Comment: http://latexcolor.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following answer from @Teddy

For rgb values between `0` and `255`, `RGB` is used rather than `rgb`.

Thus,

```
\definecolor{TigerOrange}{RGB}{249,104,21}
```

Comment: Maybe the color should have a the name `Tiger Orange` since it is not really red in my opinion.

Comment: Quite right about your point. Updated. Have not found any indications whether spaces or punctuation are allowed in the colour name for `\definecolor[⟨type⟩]{⟨name⟩}{⟨model-list⟩}{⟨spec-list⟩}`.  So I have used `CamelCase` by defining the name as `TigerOrange`.

Comment: You are right. The `xcolor` manual states (on page 12 [v2.14]): "Actually, besides letters and digits, certain other characters do also work for ⟨name⟩ declarations, but the given restriction avoids misunderstandings and ensures compatibility with future extensions of xcolor." So, the use of a space should probably be discouraged (even if it might work) and CamelCase is the way to go here.